# How to add prefix "token" on django-yasg?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've installed `django-rest-framework` and `django-yasg` to generate the swagger documentation, when i try to use the ui from `django-yasg` the authentication does not use the prefix `Token` on the `Authentication` header, e.g:

Header needed for `django-rest-framework`:

> "Authentication: Token XXX"

Header generated by the `django-yasg`:

> "Authentication: XXX"

I also have found this issue; https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/367
saying that i need to add the prefix `token` through the swagger-ui, but how can i do this?

This my `swagger settings`:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'Token': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
        },
    },
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False
}
```

How can i set the prefix on the swagger-ui so the user does have to write it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, this is what `drf-yasg` is capable for now. It just wasn't designed to support `JWT` token since it only implemented [openapi 2.0](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#security-scheme-object/).

```py
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an work-around by use `apiKey` for developers to use `bearer jwt`.(It seems to be firstly written in an issue in `drf-yasg` github repo by the author). [Openapi 2.0](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#security-scheme-object/)'s `SECURITY DEFINITION` includes `apikey`,`basic` and `oauth2`.It didn't included the format of `jwt` token.

If you wanna use swaager for your api document and also need that `Bearer` prefix, try those generators who support [openapi 3.0](https://swagger.io/specification/#jwt-bearer-sample), check this link and you'll find that it natively supports JWT Bearer. It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "http",
  "scheme": "bearer",
  "bearerFormat": "Bearer", # or whatever prefix you wish
}
```

The author of `drf-yasg` recommended `drf-spectacular` in `readme.md` of `drf-yasg`'s repo.

> If you are looking to add Swagger/OpenAPI support to a new project you might want to take a look at drf-spectacular, which is an actively maintained new library that shares most of the goals of this project, while working with OpenAPI 3.0 schemas.
>
> OpenAPI 3.0 provides a lot more flexibility than 2.0 in the types of API that can be described. drf-yasg is unlikely to soon, if ever, get support for OpenAPI 3.0.

Just like this pic.
[drf-spectacular demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq0z0.png)

To be honest, I would say that drf-yasg is now slowing down its developing process. Maybe the author is developing to support for openapi 3.0. I recently found a bug, then I post an issue. Later on I fixed that bug and made a [pr](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/pull/682), however it has been 11 days and there's no reply at all. Seems like `drf-yasg` need some certain time to support openapi 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
        }
    }
}
```

In swagger-ui type "token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".

Comment: I'm sorry if was not clear, what i want is that the "Token" prefix is already defined so the user does not have to write "Token xxx"

Comment: @RafaAcioly were you able to figure it out? I also don't want the user to write Token XXX

Comment: @palAlaa no, I've also asked on the git repo and that's the answer that they gave me: https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/367#issuecomment-501494227

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
    'Bearer': {
        'type': 'apiKey',
        'name': 'Authorization',
        'in': 'header'
    }
}
```

see image

On the Authorization screen add

Bearer xxxxx

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG0Dl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHyZS.png)

Comment: For those who are having issue to login:

In the form type: Bearer <access_token>

Answer (score 0):

In the upper-right part, you have the "Authorization" button. Go to it and paste token as I did in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry it was not clear, what I want is that the "Token" prefix is already defined so the user does not have to write "Token"

Answer (score 0):

A Solution to this with DRF_YASG After The settings

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
        }
    }
}
```

Add Bearer When Authorizing it works for now that is

Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

where xxxx is your access token